# Move an element only to the left with negative margin, but element also moves to the top

Tags: html, css

The paragraph with the class "negative" should move only to the left. But when I put a negative margin, the element also moves to the top.
Why is this so and how can I fix it?

Code without negative margin:

```css
.negative {  }

div{
  background-color:red;
}

.negative{
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div><p class="negative">...</p><p>...</p></div>
```

Code with negative margin:

```css
.negative { margin: 0 -30px; }

div{
  background-color:red;
}

.negative{
 background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div><p class="negative">...</p><p>...</p></div>
```

Comment: Because you set the top (and bottom) margin to zero in `margin: 0 -30px;` which removes the default margin on the `<p>`. How do you fix it? Don't set it to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add margin-left property. display: block not necessary - it is default css property for p element, but in case you will switch to span or something else you need to confirm that element is a block or something similar to be affected by margin-left.

```css
.negative { margin-left: -5px; }

div{
  background-color:red;
}

.negative{
 background-color:blue;
}

p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p class="negative">...</p>
<p>...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned making sure you dont set your top/bottom margin to 0. The way that you can specifically pick the left margin is "margin-left:-30px;".

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving margin-left to your element like given in the below example:

HTML:

```
<p class="negative"></p>
```

CSS:

```
.negative{margin-left:30px;}
```